# How to print an array in a range in C?

Tags: c

I try to make an menu for array, but when I create a function to print out an array in a range, for example, I input 45, 65, 78, 87, 98 to the array, when I select 4 and the min is 45, max is 87, the output is 45, 65, 78, 87, 43. I don't really know where is 43 coming from, every time I test it, 43 always in the end of the output, can someone help me please.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAXN 100
int isFull(int*a, int n)
{   return n==MAXN;
}
int add(int value, int*a, int*pn)
{   a[*pn]=value;
    (*pn)++;
}
int isEmpty(int*a, int n)
{   return n==0;
}
int search(int x, int*a, int n)
{   int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) if(a[i]==x) return i;
    return -1;
}
void print(int*a, int n)
{   int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    printf("%d,", a[i]);
}
void printvalueinrange(int*a, int n)
{   int i, min, max;
    printf("Enter minimum value:");
    scanf("%d", &min);
    printf("Enter maximum value:");
    scanf("%d", &max);
    for(i=0; i<=sizeof(a); i++)
    if(a[i]>=min&&a[i]<=max) printf("%d,", a[i]);
}
void ascSort(int*a, int n)
{   int minIndex;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {   minIndex=i;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        if(a[minIndex]>a[j]) minIndex=j;
        if(minIndex>i)
        {   int t=a[minIndex];
            a[minIndex]=a[i];
            a[i]=t;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d,", a[i]);
}
int main()
{   int n=0, i, choice, a[MAXN], value, pos, min, max;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1-Add a value\n");
        printf("2-Search a value\n");
        printf("3-Print out the array\n");
        printf("4-Print out values in a range\n");
        printf("5-Print out the array in ascending order\n");
        printf("6-Quit\n");
        printf("Select an operation\n=====================\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch(choice)
        {   case 1: 
                if(isFull(a,n)) printf("Sorry, there is no more space for you to add more value.\n");
                else
                {   printf("Input an added value:");
                    scanf("%d", &value);
                    add(value, a, &n);
                    printf("Added\n");
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(isEmpty(a,n)) printf("Sorry, the array is empty.\n");
                else
                {   printf("Input the value you want to search:");
                    scanf("%d", &value);
                    int pos=search(value, a, n);
                    if(pos<0)   printf("Not found!\n");
                    else printf("Position is found:%d\n", pos);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(isEmpty(a,n)) printf("Sorry, the array is empty.\n");
                else print(a,n);
                break;
            case 4:
                if(isEmpty(a,n)) printf("Sorry, the array is empty.\n");
                else printvalueinrange(a,n);
                break;
            case 5:
                if(isEmpty(a,n)) printf("Sorry, the array is empty.\n");
                else ascSort(a,n);
                break;
            default : printf("Have a nice day!\n");
        }
    }
    while(choice>0 && choice<6);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: correct the for-loop condition as: for(i=0; i<n; i++); in your printvalueinrange() function .

Answer (score 1):

In your `printvalueinrange` function you use `sizeof(a)` which is wrong, because `a` is a pointer and getting its size will give you the size of the *pointer* and not what it points to. Use `n` instead, like you do in your other functions.

And of course change the loop termination condition from `<=` to `<`, so you don't go out of bounds. *Also* like you do in your other functions.